# single line comment breaks javascript execution

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I load this html into webview with `webview.loadData( data, "text/html", null);`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
 <div ID="mydiv" style="width:100px; height:100px; border-style:solid;">
 </div>
</body>

<script>
mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
//comment
mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
</script>

</html>
```

This is just a square div with red background. JavaScript in webview is enabled.
But line below `//comment` does't work. Without comment it works as intended.
Can you confirm this?
sdk 25

Comment: Comment doesn't break it for me.

Comment: My page actually works correctly if I load it from server using loadUrl() and fails if I load it  from string.

Answer (score 1):

try multi line commenting with use( /* */).